# Exporting 3D contours to DXF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, contour

I used to work with QGIS, now I don't remember the stages I have done. So,I wanted to ask you about it.

My problem is, when I export 3d contours (that was made from SRTM DEM by doing a [raster>extraction>contour] proccesing) to DXF file I realized that contours have bigger intervals than reality.

I got an assumption that is resulted like this because of the projection method I used. IT seems like I got intervals in degree. But I changed it to another CRS that was written projected near it but the result doesn't changed.

How can I select true CRS when I export 3D contours to DXF?